# SSIS converting yearweek to date

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file that contains a column with YearWeek that looks like this: 201905  (the files are created once every week so weeknumber will change)

I would like to convert this in SSIS to the date of sunday week 5 2019 (2019-02-03)

I have googled but not found a solution to this anywere.

Comment: You could write some code which does that? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and [writing the perfect question](//github.com/shlomif/writing-the-perfect-question/blob/master/README.asciidoc) by John Skeet. Also, be sure to take the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Here's a tip: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf233caf-4ccd-4bca-add2-b5eb467f2dd4/convert-week-number-to-date-of-1st-day-of-that-week You should be able to put that together with `substr` and `convert` to do what you need.

Comment: Instead of parsing that date, use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). You could add the `YYYYWW` value *and* the week's start date as separate fields. Once you do that you'd only need to lookupt the YYYYWW vale in the Calendar table and retrieve the week start date